# Typescript getter and setter error

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-services

Ok it's my first day doing some Angular 2 using typescript and I am try to make a simple getter and setter service.

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {

  private _todos:Array = [];

  get todos():Array {
    return this._todos;
  }

  set todos(value:Array) {
    this._todos = value;
  }

}
```

Can anyone explain why the Typescript compiler is throwing the following error as I think it should be ok.

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/testguy/WebstormProjects/angular2-seed/src/app/services/todo-service.ts:6:17 
Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /Users/testguy/WebstormProjects/angular2-seed/src/app/services/todo-service.ts:8:14 
Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).

ERROR in [default] /Users/testguy/WebstormProjects/angular2-seed/src/app/services/todo-service.ts:12:18 
Generic type 'Array<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should really need to mention which kind of `Array` you want while defining it, `MyClass` can be `string`/`number`(datatype)

**Code**

```
export class TodoService {

  private _todos:Array<MyClass> = [];

  get todos():Array<MyClass> {
    return this._todos;
  }

  set todos(value:Array<MyClass>) {
    this._todos = value;
  }

}
```

Comment: If any one else stumbles upon this you need to define the type as an Array and then inside the <> create a class which is a model which describes the structure of the array item.