# Naming arrays in Angular 2 template

Tags: angular

Is there a cleaner way to write this?

```
   <a *ngIf="array[some_property_exist] && array[some_property_exist].length > 0" href="array[some_property_exist] | somePipe">
     <span>{{array[some_property_exist].some_other_property</span>
   </a>
```

Is there a way to alias `array[some_property_exist]` to a variable in the template?

Comment: In angular 2 you can use getters and setters as aliases to the values you a re looking for

Comment: Can you give me an example or link to show how they're used?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664824/typescript-getter-and-setter-error